# Using custom color as background did not work

Tags: swiftui, colors

Custom color in asset folder so I could use with things like foregroundColor background and other.

I give this color name

```
 "CL1"
```

Example foregroundColor(Color("CL1")) background(Color("CL1"))

My problem right now I can't use this as background because i tried and its not working. Also no error alert.

```
Color("Cl1").ignoresSafeArea() //background
```

When apply with text it work.

```
Text("test").foregroundColor(Color("CL1"))
```

[my proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncMV8.jpg)

Comment: Needed more context and/or minimal reproducible example - where did you use it as background? Does it work as foreground color?

Comment: Okay sir i added picture of my process with foregroundColor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with ZStack

```
ZStack {
  Color("CL1").ignoresSafeArea()
  Text("test")
}
```